# Traversing through a generic collection

Tags: java, generics

Lets say I have function

```
void sell(Collection<? extends T> items) {
   for (? e : items) {
      stock.add(e);
   }
}
```

as you can see i want to iterate through the items, but I cannot use the notation `? e`, because it spits out the error "illegal start of expression".

Comment: if your traversing is just to add all of them, you could also use stock.addAll(items)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each of the items in the collection is a `T` or a sub-class of `T`, so you can use `T`. You don't know the *exact* types of the items but that doesn't matter; you do know their common base class.

```
for (T e: items) {
    stock.add(e);
}
```